# Pass multiple arguments to Excel Macro from Access?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a sub (macro) in Excel that I want to be able to call from Access, which looks like this:

```
Sub myMacro(param1 as string, param2 as string)
...
End Sub
```

In Access, I have:

```
xlBook.Application.Run "myMacro", string1, string2
```

But I get the error :

> Runtime Error 450:
>
> Wrong number of arguments or invaluid property assignment

How do I pass multiple parameter to Excel?

Comment: Did you define string1 and string2 as strings? Otherwise, it seems ok as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153307

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Remou's comment, I checked the variable types being passed.

In this case, `string2` was a Variant that was supposed to hold a String of numbers, but when the string of numbers got stored in `string2` (the Variant), it was converted to a number (stored within a variant [?]).

Nonetheless, stricter (and thus correct) type declarations solved the issue.